# How to play file from Library by MediaElement?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I can play files only from application storage, but, I have to play file from Library or another source. The I try to:

```
        var storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("C:\\Users\\admin\\Music\\line.mp3"));
        var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

        mediaElement.SetSource(stream, storageFile.ContentType);

        mediaElement.Play();
```

It's gives exception: 
"An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Polar.exe but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range."

I tried mediaElement.Source() to, but element is not playing the sound. No exception, no anything.

I think it's foolish problem, but I can't find solution. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to play audio files from library, then you need to use `KnownFolders`. `GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync` won't work.

```
var storageFile = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync("line.mp3");
var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
mediaElement.SetSource(stream, storageFile.ContentType);
mediaElement.Play();
```

If you want enumerate all the media file or all the folders then use this.

```
var AllStorageFiles = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync();
var AllStorageFolders = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFoldersAsync();
```

Comment: What should I do if I want  to access to root file, ex. "C:\ex.mp3"?

Comment: Where I can read deeply about accessing in Windows Store Apps?

Comment: You can't access directly. You need to use `FileOpenPicker`.

Comment: http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2012/05/21/winrt-folders-access/ & http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html