# File Uri to StorageFile or Stream

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, filestream

I have only file Uri to open in the MediaElement.
How to use _MediaElement.SetSource with Uri? My way is based on this example:

```cs
var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
mediaControl.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
```

But, I have only Uri from the file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `Uri`, you should use the `Source` property on the `MediaElement`:

```
mediaControl.Source = myUri;
```

`SetSource` is more appropriate if you have a `stream` object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576394/how-to-play-file-from-library-by-mediaelement