# How play a .mp3 (or other) file in a UWP app?

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I try this:

```
PlayMusic = new MediaElement();
PlayMusic.AudioCategory = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AudioCategory.Media;

PlayMusic.Source = new Uri(@"C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\C:\Users\user\Desktop\Kill The Alarm - Begin Again.mp3");
PlayMusic.Play();
```

No more error messages appear on the display (try catch runs clean through).

Sorry for the short description...
I can read and understand English very well but it is difficult for me to talk and write.

Comment: try wrapping the long file name around single quotes or rename the file to have no spaces and see if it works

Comment: no change by this means. :/

Comment: `C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\C:\Users\paulk\Desktop\Kill The Alarm - Begin Again.mp3` is not a valid path, you're repeating the substring to your Desktop folder.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every Windows Store App has three folders. A Local folder, a Roaming folder and a Temp folder. Each is accessed the same way. Local is meant to store assets in a local, application-specific folder.

Here is the answer:

```
StorageFolder Folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
                Folder = await Folder.GetFolderAsync("MyFolder");
                StorageFile sf = await Folder.GetFileAsync("MyFile.mp3");
                PlayMusic.SetSource(await sf.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read), sf.ContentType);
                PlayMusic.Play();
```

MfG.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot just read any file on your file system like this with windows store applications.

If you just want to test it:

1. Add the file to your project in Visual Studio
2. Change your file’s "Build Action" to "Content".
3. Change "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always".

What you probably want to do is explained in the section, **Read Local files w/o a Picker** from [this article](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576394/how-to-play-file-from-library-by-mediaelement) might also be helpful.

Comment: Yeaaaaah! Thank You Yo Much! I did it! (i post the solution as Answer!)

Answer (score 3):

Put mySong.mp3 in your Assets folder.  Then in Visual Studio, right click on your Assets folder and select "add existing item".  Add mySong.mp3 FROM your Assets folder.
In XAML, add a player:

```
 <MediaElement x:Name="myPlayer"
 AutoPlay="True" />
```

In c#, mySong.mp3 will play when you set the source:

```
 Uri newuri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/mySong.mp3");
 myPlayer.Source = newuri;
```

Answer (score 0):

Register the [MediaFailed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.mediafailed.aspx)-Event of the MediaElement and check if it gets raised. The ExceptionRoutedEventArgs passed to the method, should contain information about, why the file cannot be played.

Comment: Try including the audio file in your solution and then change the URI

Comment: PlayMusic.Source = new Uri(@"ms-appx://Sleep/Media/KillTheAlarm.mp3");

No changes :/