# MediaElement doesn't play mp3

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Trying to make some mediaplayer app. I put the mediaelement on wpf, wrote code to open media. But when i try to play it nothing is happening...

```
public void ContinueFileOpenPicker(FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (StorageFile file in args.Files)
        {
            if (playlist.Contains(file.Path)) return;
            playlist.Add(file.Path);
        }
    }
}

private void PlayButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyMedia.Source = new Uri(playlist[0], UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    MyMedia.Play();
}
```

Checked that mediaelement source isn't empty, it has a right value of path.
Try to rebuild like that, still doesnt work

```
private async void PlayButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var stream = await Playlist[0].OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        MyMedia.SetSource(stream, Playlist[0].ContentType);
        MyMedia.Play();
    }
```

Comment: Make sure the MediaElement is added to the app, not in the code, but somewhere in the ui. You can make it hidden but it should be there in the root grid just after the window.

Comment: some example please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play file from Library by MediaElement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576394/how-to-play-file-from-library-by-mediaelement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry it was my mistake.

Into my XAML, I forgot that the `AutoPlay` property of the `MediaElement` control was set to `false`.

This solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you need to watch out.

```
foreach (StorageFile file in args.Files)
{
    if(playlist.Contains(file.Path))
    {
       return;// Dont return use continue. You will probably skip rest of the files.
    }
    playlist.Add(file.Path);
}
```

Add a Watch/Quickwatch to see if the  `new Uri(playlist[0], UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)` points to a right location.

Comment: I think it is right "D:\a\3 Doors Down – Here Without You.mp3" if "D:\" emulated sdcard

Answer (score 0):

Setup source from storage file:

```
var storageFile = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync("line.mp3");
var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
mediaElement.SetSource(stream, storageFile.ContentType);
mediaElement.Play();
```

I got it from this answer: [How to play file from Library by MediaElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576394/how-to-play-file-from-library-by-mediaelement)

Comment: Can you provide me a sample?

Comment: private async void PlayButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var stream = await Playlist[0].OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        MyMedia.SetSource(stream, Playlist[0].ContentType);
        MyMedia.Play();
    }

Comment: where you declared media element?

Comment: did you mean?
    <MediaElement x:Name="MyMedia" 
                      MediaFailed="MyMedia_OnMediaFailed" ></MediaElement>

Comment: yes, sure. All is good. I don't see any problem. can you send me an archive?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103424/discussion-between-yura-gumenyuk-and-andrii-krupka).

Comment: sorry...i get it....it was some kind of stupid mistake...... i set autoplay property to false, and somehow it does such a bad thing